# Light in glass/water

Tags: optics, visible-light, refraction, wavelength

When light enters water, the light changes their direction because they only use 75% of their speed in water, because the interactions with the electrons, the wavelength of the photon changes. We SEE the light change direction, but why can't we see the wavelength change too? Shouldn't wee see another color because the wavelength changed in the water? I asked someone and he said that we only see the light that reached our eye, so the light that came out of the glass, that wavelength was the same as the wavelength before it entered the glass. That makes sense, but why DO we see the direction change and not the wavelength?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Light dispersion in water](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/70366/light-dispersion-in-water)

Answer (score 4):

The wavelength is the speed divided by the frequency (and the frequency is constant). Light has some wavelength in air; then it decreases when it enters class; then it leaves the glass and its back to the exact same wavelength it was in when it was in the air before. Then it enters your eye, where light has a new speed in the fluid of your eye. Hopefully this clarifies things - light's wavelength isn't *permanently* changed by entering glass. It's only changed when it's in the glass. And when you see it, it's not in glass - it's in your eye. The wavelength a beam of light has while it's in your eye does not depend on whether it went through glass at some point in its trajectory.

Comment: Note that your eye responds to the frequency rather than the wavelength.  The retina responds to what happens where the light wave interacts with the cells, the rate at which the light wave oscillates at the retina.